# Passing an JSON array to MVC Web API via POST

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My Code is as follows:

```
{
  "myImage": [{
    "Image": "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",
    "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",
    "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",
    "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",
    "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"
  }]
}
```

I am passing the array(POST) through postman. How do I read the value of array in my MVC  WEB API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test
{
    public MyImage myImage{get;set;}
}

public class MyImage
{
    public List<string> Image{get;set;}
}
```

Use Like that and call Test() In your post method as parameter 
    and put image data also in curly braces  because json work with key value pair.

Hope it will work.